# React Native: Background Image not being shown

Tags: javascript, image, react-native

I was trying to build a background image component in React Native, which shall only be used for local image (jpg & png) loading (hence the use of URI for iOS), but the Image does not show up

```
import React from 'react';
import {Image} from 'react-native';

const BackgroundImage = (props) => {
    return (
        <Image source={{uri: props.img }}  style={styles.backgroundImage}>
            {props.children}
        </Image>
    )
};
const styles = {
    backgroundImage: {
        flex: 1,
        width: null,
        height: null,
        resizeMode: 'cover'
    }
};

export {BackgroundImage};
```

Usage:

```
const App = () => (
    <BackgroundImage img='./assets/img/gradient.jpg'>
        <View style={{flex: 1}}>
             /* More things */
        </View>
    </BackgroundImage>
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be `require` not `uri`. As you have used prop it needs to be stored in var first and then you can pass it to Image because require will not work if you directly pass prop to it.

Example:

```
let imagePath = require("../../assets/list.png");
<Image style={{height: 50, width: 50}} source={imagePath} />
```

or

```
<Image style={[this.props.imageStyle]}
    source={this.props.imagePath
    ? this.props.imagePath
    : require('../theme/images/resource.png')}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to check if your Image-URI is http or https. IOS only allow HTTPS.
It is because of App Transport Security (ATS)